# How to delete a node from XML using XML::Simple?

Tags: xml, perl

I need to delete a node from XML using `XML::Simple`.

My XML looks like:

```
<Install>
<version >
<number>6.0</number>
<build>1014445</build>
<path>path</path>
<kind>native</kind>
</version>
<version >
<number>6.1</number>
<build>1025654</build>
<path>path</path>
<kind>native</kind>
</version>
</Install>
```

I need to delete a node matching a particular number under `version`.  For example, I need to delete the node with number=6.0.

Updated XML will look like:

```
<Install>
<version >
<number>6.1</number>
<build>1025654</build>
<path>path</path>
<kind>native</kind>
</version>
</Install>
```

Comment: There has been a flurry of `XML::Simple` questions recently. Are you constrained to using it, or can you use, say, `XML::Twig` instead? The documentation for `XML::Simple` itself says that *❝The use of this module in new code is discouraged❞*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a solution using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig). As I said in my comment, the `XML::Simple` module is not a good choice unless you *have* no choice

`XML::Twig` uses a subset of XPath, so the expression used to find the required `version` element is different from the one in the `XML::LibXML` solution

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile('install.xml');

for my $number ( $twig->findnodes('/Install/version/number[string()="6.0"]') ) {
    $number->parent->delete;
}

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented_c');
$twig->print;
```

#### output

```
<Install>
  <version>
    <number>6.1</number>
    <build>1025654</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>native</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

---

#### Update

If you want to make the program write directly to the new XML file instead of using the command line to redirect the output, then you just need to `open` the new file and pass the file handle to the `print` method call

Like this

```
open my $xml_fh, '>', 'install_new.xml' or die $!;
$twig->set_pretty_print('indented_c');
$twig->print($xml_fh);
```

---

#### Update 2

To specify the version number to be deleted as a variable you could interpolate the string's value into the XPath expression

```
my $filter = '6.0';

for my $number ( $twig->findnodes(qq{/Install/version/number[string()="$filter"]} } {
    ...
}
```

but it is best to iterate over all of the `number` elements and write an explicit comparison, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile('install.xml');

my $filter = '6.0';

for my $number ( $twig->findnodes('/Install/version/number') ) {
  $number->parent->delete if $number->trimmed_text eq $filter;
}

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented_c');
$twig->print;
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin but this code dosen't save the update to the file which I am looking for.

Comment: All you need to do is redirect the output to the file you want `perl remove_v6.pl > install_new.xml`. Or I've updated my solution to show how to do it directly from the program if you prefer

Comment: Ya That will be great if you can update your solution, as I said I am new to perl.

Comment: @user3649361: It's usually more convenient to get the Perl program to write to STDOUT. Then you can put the output where you like using the command line as I described. Just enter the  command as I showed in my comment, using your name for the program file instead of `remove_v6.pl`

Comment: @Bordin I need to maintain the same file so need to do it through program only.

Comment: @user3649361: Probably the easiest way is to just interpolate the variable into the XPath expression, but it is nicer to do an explicit string comparison. I've updated my solution

Answer (score 5):

It's next to impossible to get XML::Simple to produce the same output it read in. For this and other reasons, the module's documentation states

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged

I'd use XML::LibXML.

```perl
$_->unbindNode() for $doc->findnodes( '/Install/version[number="6.0"]' );
```

Comment: I have perl 5, version 20 , I tried to install XML::LibXML but was not able to, I searched it in perl ppm UI but I didn't find it there.

Comment: In your situation, I'd use XML::Twig

Comment: XML::Twig  It is installed by default or I have to installed it to.I want to use a module which is installed by default and dosen't require installation because the script will be run across many systems so default module suites more.

Comment: Perl does not come with any XML parsers. Just include `ppm install XML::Twig` in your application's installation procedure.

Comment: thanks, but for my perl version I am not able to find both of the module which you suggested.which version do they support.

Comment: @user3649361:  *Strawberry Perl* comes with both `XML::LibXML` and `XML::Twig` installed. Are you running ActivePerl? `ppm install XML-Twig` should work for you

Comment: Then use `cpan XML::Twig` as the rest of the world does. `ppm` is just a convenience.

Comment: Yes @Borodin I am running Active perl.

Comment: Ya I have installed twig I am able to run your code but need to save the changes to file also @Borodin.

Comment: huh? My code isn't for XML::Twig. I think you replied to the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

I like XML::DT (I am its author)...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::DT;
use strict;
my $filename = shift;

print pathdt($filename,
 'number'        => sub{father(del => 1) if($c eq "6.1"); toxml; },
 'version[@del]' => sub{"" },    
)
```