# How to extract only parent elements condition on specific values in child element?

Tags: xml, perl, text-extraction

I would like to extract all parents which have certain values in child element. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
  <row>
    <name>snake</name>
    <category>reptile</category>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>frog</name>
    <category>amphibian</category>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>racoon</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>horse</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
   </row>
</dataset>
```

I would like to extract only mammals. The result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
 <row>
    <name>racoon</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
   </row>
  <row>
    <name>horse</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
   </row>
</dataset>
```

Usually I use `XML::LibXML` for XML processing, but I would use any other library which can do this extraction. Is it possible to do this with Perl?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do this with Perl?

Everything's possible with Perl!

Here is one way to do it with [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).  It uses an Xpath-type expression to delete all `category` elements which are not `mammal`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $file = 'input.xml';
my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parsefile($file);
for my $cat( $twig->findnodes('/dataset/row/category[string()!="mammal"]') ) {
    $cat->parent->delete();
}
$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print();
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
  <row>
    <name>racoon</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>horse</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
  </row>
</dataset>
```

---

I leveraged this code heavily from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590582/197758).  I don't consider this an exact duplicate since the sense of the find is inverted.

Answer (score 2):

Another `XML::Twig` approach that removes the rows as the document is being parsed:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig =
  XML::Twig->new(
                 twig_roots =>
                 {
                  row => \&delete_non_mammals
                 },
                 twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
                 pretty_print => "indented"
                );

$twig->parsefile("input.xml");
$twig->flush;

sub delete_non_mammals {
  my @cats = $_->findnodes('category');
  if ($cats[0]->text ne "mammal") {
    $_->delete;
  } else {
    $_->flush;
  }
}
```

Or not using perl at all, but the always-useful [`xmlstarlet`](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) program (Useful if this is something you want to do from a shell script):

```bash
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//row[category!="mammal"]' input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
  <row>
    <name>racoon</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>horse</name>
    <category>mammal</category>
  </row>
</dataset>
```

Comment: This approach will generate a lot of extra whitespace; if that matters to you, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76765127/9952196) for how to strip it out.

Answer (score 2):

"Keeping the mammals" is a way of saying "deleting the non-mammals". With that in mind, there are solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31589948/589924). Adapting the XML::LibXML solution found there gives us the following:

```perl
$_->unbindNode() for $doc->findnodes( '/dataset/row[category!="mammal"]' );
```